# a word for "not in a satisfactory standard, but bearable"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request

I have a laptop bought five years ago, though it gets very slow and has many unnecessary programs running, it can still work.
How am I supposed to describe this?
Can I say "*it can barely work*"? Does that sound more like I can not live with it?

Edit:
Sorry for the ambiguity, but actually I'm looking for an expression that's more like "*thought it has such problems, **but I can still live with it***".

Comment: That works. If you want to show less possibility for that to work, you can use other modals like *may barely work* or *might barely work.*

Comment: @Ustanak Thank you and sorry for the ambiguity, but how about actually I want to show more possibility for that to work?

Comment: You can use *despite being in no optimal conditions, it can barely work.*

Comment: Actually, the suggestions embedded in your question are pretty good. For example, _**bearable**_ can work. (Question: _Do you like your laptop?_ Answer: _No, not really. It's bearable. I can't wait to get a new one._) Same with ***I can live with it***. (Question: _Do you like your laptop?_ Answer: _No, but I can live with it._) Those answers are very natural, understandable, idiomatic English.

Comment: "Tolerable" is another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

'It can barely work' means that you almost cannot live with it. 'It can barely work' sounds to me worse than 'though it gets very slow and has many unnecessary programs running, it can still work'.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for the ambiguity, but how about I want to be sounded like emphasizing the fact "it can still work"?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to describe how poorly it performs:

> It barely works

would be idiomatic.

However, "It can barely work" is not idiomatic.

With "*can* barely" you would need {something particular} as the complement.

> It can barely *render an image*.
>
> It can barely *boot up*.
>
> It can barely *open a spreadsheet*.

The complement of "can barely" is {do *something*}, whereas "work" is more or less a synonym here for bare "do".